# How to picture vibrational overtones of water?

Tags: water, frequency, vibrations, absorption, harmonics

Im trying to understand the colour of water. The absorption occurs because of some of the vibrational overtones of water.

> The absorption band at 698 nm (14300 cm−1) is a 3rd overtone (n=4)

The three fundamental vibration types $v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_3$ I understand visually, however Im struggling to understand what the combinations and overtones of these vibrations are.

> An overtone is any frequency greater than the fundamental frequency

What does an overtone physically mean in the context of molecular vibration?
is $v_1+v_3$ simple both of those vibrations occurring at once? what about $5v_3$?

Comment: The color of water is also going to be affected by the electronic state gaps and the rotational fine structure on top of the vibrational bands. Even then, you have to consider absorption intensity, light scattering, etc. Overall, you are asking a lot if you want to get the color of water right from first principles.

Answer (score 0):

When the potential is not exactly harmonic (and of course in reality it never is), a charge moving in the potential will not execute a purely harmonic motion. Its electrical field will be periodic, and a Fourier transform will show overtones: components at integer multiples of the fundamental.

Answer (score -1):

An overtone, more precisely is an integer multiple of a base (the least) frequency. If the base frequency is $\nu$ then the first overtone, also known as the second harmonic, is the frequency $2\nu$. And so on for subsequent overtones.

[image]

These quantised (multiples of a base) frequency is a feature of a system that is constrained to move within a fixed boundary. The condition is that the wave must go to zero at the boundaries. Guitar strings, water ripples in a box and so on are examples of this. The smallest wave that can be fit within these boundaries is the half-wave that is shown in red. The next one that can fit inside is the full wave. And so on.

Something similar happens in the case of a water molecule. To describe the underlying process we need to use quantum mechanics. But the gist is that is this case the boundary condition is that the probability of the bond length being infinite must be zero. And this leads to the wave function of the system, near the equilibrium bond length to look like

[image]

In the case of vibrational modes of water molecule the vibration is bound by the binding energy of the bond. And the $n^{th}$ overtones represent the molecule vibrating with a frequency that $n$ times the base frequency.

Comment: Your functions are orthogonal, there will be no overlap, no radiative transitions between them. And there are no fixed boundaries for molecular vibrations.

Comment: My answer was not clear. I didn’t mean that the sinusoids represented the system of water molecule. It was only to explain the concept of overtones. However, why would there be no radiative transition between two sinusoidal states?

Comment: Overtones do not hve to be integer multiples of the fundamental. The harmonics are overtones but the overtones are not necessary harmonics. In the OP reference they say that the overtones are sligtly less than the integer multiples of the fundamental. So they are not proper harmonics.